# Reactify, Browserify and Gulp: TypeError: Object #<Transform> has no method 'transform'

Tags: javascript, gulp, reactjs, browserify

This is the error when, through command-line, I do `gulp scripts`:

> TypeError: Object #< Transform > has no method 'transform'

This is `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp            = require ('gulp')
    , browserify    = require ('gulp-browserify')
    , source        = require ('vinyl-source-stream')
    , reactify      = require ('reactify');

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
  browserify('./assets/js/main.js')
    .transform(reactify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./static/js'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['scripts']);
```

I really don't know how to fix this. I searched on the internet, but nothing I found came close to my specific error.

Answer (score 5):

There is some problems with your task.

First, you have to use `gulp.src` to get your *main.js* file. Second, `transform` is an option of *gulp-browserify*, not something you want to pipe your stream on, same for `bundle`.

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
  return gulp.src('./assets/js/main.js')
    .pipe(browserify({
      transform: [reactify]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./static/js'));
});
```

If you want something that is more like your first attempt, you don't need *gulp-browserify*, but *browserify* alone, there is a quite good article on how to use *ReactJs* with *Browserify* and *gulp* [here](http://truongtx.me/2014/07/18/using-reactjs-with-browserify-and-gulp/).

Comment: And if would I to use browserify-shim?

Comment: It's also a transform and *gulp-browserify* allow on array so I think you're okay [link](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim/blob/97d416cb3bc2ef531fae05a8eed4c86700ba4dc8/README.md).

Comment: `gulp-browserify` allows me, `browserify` doesn't. I can't see how I can get them working together. Can you show me an example? And your fragment of code returns me `TypeError: Object #<Browserify> has no method 'pipe'`.

Comment: With a `var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');` ? It's strange. I just saw that *gulp-browserify* is [blacklisted](https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/issues/47) so you really should go with *browserify*. There is a lot of examples at [this link](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim/blob/97d416cb3bc2ef531fae05a8eed4c86700ba4dc8/README.md) about using *shim* with it

Answer (score 4):

You use `vinyl-source-stream` with `browserify` not with `gulp-browserify`.  You're mixing the two.

```
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
    ,source = require('vinyl-source-stream')
    ,browserify = require('browserify') //not gulp-browerify
    ,babelify = require('babelify')
    ,uglify = require('gulp-uglify')
    ;

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
  var bundler = browserify('./assets/js/main.js');

  return bundler
    .transform(babelify, {presets: ["es2015", "stage-1", "react"]})
    .bundle({standalone: 'noscope'})
    .pipe(source('main.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./static/js'));
});
```

from https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/369

---

Edit: using babelify instead of reactify (which was deprecated)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion... `vinyl-source-stream` is used with `browserify` in gulp... if you're using `gulp-browserify` it works differently.  It's better to just use browserify, and use `vinyl-source-stream` to convert the stream into a gulp stream.